# The list doesn't exist. Please fix the ListUrl attribute

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, document-library

I saved a site as a template and when I tried to use that template to crate a new site I got this error "The list "list1" doesn't exist. Please fix the ListUrl attribute." I looked in the source site in which I saved as a template, there is no such list with this name, I even checked if is there is any lookup field pointing to a list doesn't exist, I found nothing. Any ideas would be appropriated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try three things.

1. Check for more errors (if any) in ULS logs.
2. Rename the site template .wsp to .cab and extract the contents. Find the string "list1" in the xml files using findstr command or [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). This would give a clue about list1.
3. Search for list1 in SQL database tables - though not recommended and should be treated as a last resort.